# Visual studio - javascript errors

Tags: visual-studio

I am getting a lot of warnings with my ember app. Basically a lot of these in the .js files:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
```

import gives a syntax error, and the same line expects ';', twice (after Ember and after from).

Also in html files:

```
<head>
{{content-for 'head'}}
</head>
```

Here head is underlined and the error says that text is not allowed inside the head element (only tags are allowed).

How exactly can I hide these errors?

Also, I cant install any packages as I opened this project as a folder, not a solution. How can I turn it into a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `Tools` > `Options` > `Text-Editor` > `HTML` > `Advanced` > `Validation` and/or `Errors as warning` you can disable validation/errors for your `<head>` issue.

Installing 'Web Essentials' (it's not a package so should be ok I guess) for example it comes with a lot of support for JavaScript. Not sure how Ember reacts though. `Tools` > `Extensions and updates`

If all the above fails a quick search pointed me to [Ember.js MVC5 SPA Template](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9078967b-525a-469b-bb1a-6dde5e34aabf) or [EmberStudio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7cee69fc-2dcc-43be-8dad-2147a0c362f4).

It's possible these add-ons give you extra `Tools` > `Options` so definatly worth to check it out.